# Windows 8 not recognised when installing Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb

I recently got a laptop that came pre-installed with Windows 8. I would also like to run Linux, but I do not want to remove Windows, as many of the programs I use for school are only Windows-compatible.

I successfully booted using a USB into 'try Ubuntu', but when I went to install the only options were to overwrite Windows or 'something else' - it said no other operating system was detected.

I did some research into partitioning, but the guides all said to back up a Windows image (or something like that) in case something went wrong. However, I don't have any way of backing up (all my USB sticks are <4GB).

So I have a few questions:

- How do I solve the issue with Windows 8 not being recognised? Using the built-in Ubuntu 'install alongside' would be so much easier than partitioning myself (I really don't want to mess anything up)
- How big are Windows image backups? If they are <4GB I can use my USB stick and feasibly partition myself.

Comment: Is UEFI enabled or disabled?

Comment: I honestly don't know - I'm a complete novice to this part of the computing world!

Answer (score 0):

Few pieces of advice

- Create a recovery media disk of Windows 8.1. In most cases 2 DVD's are required.  (Cannot emphasis this anymore)
- Back up all your data, I am assuming you have access to required software.

**Answers** to your questions.

- **"Install Ubuntu along side windows"** options is not presented all the time (Sorry I don't have an explanation)
- Select **"Something else"**
- There are a few good tutorial and YouTube videos explaining the process. I have listed them below.

**Referances**

1. [Dual boot windows 8 and ubuntu-12-10 in uefi mode](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2013/03/12/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-04-in-uefi-mode/)
2. [Install Ubuntu Linux alongside windows](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html)
3. [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)
4. [Here is a YouTube video of someone installing Ubuntu along side windows 8](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18F3CZveMwg&feature=youtu.be)
5. [Here is another YouTube video on how to install Ubuntu along side windows 8](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LokDqte3sA4)

Comment: Thank you so much! I am working at the moment, but next time I get a break I'll watch those YouTube videos - I prefer those to worded guides.