# Windows 7 not recognised in installation

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, system-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 to dual boot on this Windows 7 64 bit laptop, but it didn't recognise Windows. Last week this machine failed to boot in Windows and all the Samsung Recovery options failed, and I didn't have a system disc, so I downloaded Windows 7 from the official digitalriver site, and managed to install it OK. From reading other threads it looks like that may be why it's not being recognised.

I just managed to install boot-repair and was given the following URL to share on the forum: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7409913/

Thanks for your help,

Andrew

P.S. I wouldn't mind too much using the BIOS to dual boot. There's 500GB altogether, and 250GB free space. Could I just install Ubuntu there, and then set the BIOS to boot to Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this another post can help you with.
The problem seems almost the same:

[Windows 8 not recognised - AskUbuntu Topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403870/windows-8-not-recognised-when-installing-ubuntu-13-10)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am hoping that somebody might be able to read my boot-info and understand what is going on and then advise. Andrew

Answer (score 0):

If your windows 7 is a 64bit, Get a 64bit ubuntu version.

I guess it will support your 64bit laptop.